# Why GRANT UPDATE on SEQUENCE in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, permissions, sequence

I have seen postgresql allowing users to Grant update on a sequence. But never seen any update query on the sequence.
Sequence values are usually changed using `ALTER SEQUENCE` command. I understand the need for `GRANT USAGE` and `GRANT SELECT` on sequences. But what exactly does a `GRANT UPDATE` on a sequence lets you do in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) says:

> `nextval ( regclass )` → `bigint`
>
> [...]
> This function requires `USAGE` or `UPDATE` privilege on the sequence.
>
> ---
>
> `setval ( regclass, bigint [, boolean ] )` → `bigint`
>
> [...]
> This function requires `UPDATE` privilege on the sequence.